# what is the difference in Java 8 Stream.parallel and Scala trait Parallelizable.par

Tags: java, scala, parallel-processing

Currently, I only know both Java 8 and Scala support parallel operation on the collection, I wrote several examples to play with it, but I am not sure what is the difference of it in term of performance, implementation technique and so on.

When I search it, I didnt get sufficient materials about it

Can someone share some experience about it ?

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that Java's are like iterators (one shot) and Scala's are like iterables.

You could take a look at the following presentation from QCon NY 2014 which compares the performance of Java 8 Streams, Scala Collections, and GS Collections parallel lazy implementations.

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/java-streams-scala-parallel-collections

**Note:** I am a developer on GS Collections